# Lazy loading angular 17 not loading the child routes

Tags: angular, angularjs, angular-routing, angular-routerlink

i am trying to implement lazy loading on admin interface. In app-routing.module file i am using the below syntax

```html
{
    path: 'admin',
    loadChildren: () => import('@/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
  },
```

and in admin-routing.module file the syntax is

```html
{
    path: '',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      {
        path: 'profile',
        component: ProfileComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'general',
        component: GeneralComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'events',
        component: EventsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'members',
        component: MembersComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'donation',
        component: DonationComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'donors',
        component: DonorsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'rules-regulations',
        component: RulesRegulationsComponent,
      },
      {
        path: 'gallery',
        component: GalleryComponent,
      },
      {
        path: '',
        component: GeneralComponent,
      },
    ],
  },
```

The issue is admin mainComponent loads correctly but the child routes admin/gallary, admin/event, etc redirects to homepage and i am getting K.noMatchError error. Please help me guys.

I want that admin/gallary, admin/event etc routes work properly.

Comment: change path: 'profile', to path: 'admin/profile' and give a try.

Comment: Can you provide the AuthGuard and try removing `canActivateChild: [AuthGuard]`? If the issue still persists, this means there is routing error, otherwise it is due to AuthGuard.

Comment: yes i have tried to remove guards but nothing resolved

Answer (score 0):

```
{
  path: 'admin',
  loadChildren: () => import('@/admin/admin.module').then(m => m.AdminModule),
},




{
  path: '', // This route is now a child of the main route
  component: MainComponent,
  canActivate: [AuthGuard],
  canActivateChild: [AuthGuard],
  children: [
    // ... other child routes
    {
      path: 'admin/gallery', // Prefixed with 'admin/'
      component: GalleryComponent,
    },
    {
      path: 'admin/events', // Prefixed with 'admin/'
      component: EventsComponent,
    },
    // ... other admin child routes
  ],
},
```

Comment: This will not working as now to browse the GalleryComponent etc, the route will be: `<domain>/admin/admin/gallery`

Comment: when i type in address bar /admin/gallery it works correctly. Also i have tried your solution but it this just changing the url in address bar but content is not updating

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your help. I have resolved the issue. Actually, i am importing BrowserAnimationModule in lazy loaded component, but it should only be included in the root module.